# How they showing the counts?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Thanks in advance..

I searched my best but couldn't find a proper answer yet.. How http://www.ryanleslie.com showing the fan page posts LIKE and Comments count here..  Please help me as I need this for one of my current project..

Thanks and Regards,
Anz

Answer (score 0):

He is using the Facebook API. You can check it out [here](http://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf)